# Add values for different years

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains information about businesses. Each row is a business. Column F has the id of the business and column Z has an integer telling me the income.  Column A has the year. I just want for every business to add the income over all the years in the dataframe. How can one do this?

I could write a loop for every business that does this but I feel sure there is a pandas way that is simple.

I have tried setting column F as the index with `df1 = df1.set_index('F')` .  Can I now somehow select by year and add those together?

Comment: Do you want total sum for all years or cumulative sum?

Comment: @EdChum I actually only have three years so I would like the sum of the incomes over those three years for each business.

Comment: I think DSM has provided this answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `groupby`.  This is covered in the tutorial [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).  For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"F": ["b1", "b1", "b2", "b3"], "A": [2001,2002,2001,2003], "Z": [100, 200, 50, 200]})
>>> df
      A   F    Z
0  2001  b1  100
1  2002  b1  200
2  2001  b2   50
3  2003  b3  200

[4 rows x 3 columns]
>>> df.groupby("F")["Z"].sum()
F
b1    300
b2     50
b3    200
Name: Z, dtype: int64
```

or maybe

```
>>> df.groupby("F", as_index=False)["Z"].sum()
    F    Z
0  b1  300
1  b2   50
2  b3  200

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

depending on whether you want the output to be a `Series` or another `DataFrame`.